# System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: minimumpoolsize (Parameter 'keyword') use PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, abp

I Created a new project(apb 4.2.2) with EF+PostgreSQL. then i have been changed connection string in appsettings.json for match my postgresql db. EX.

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=psi_pg_dev;User ID=chaoyi;Password=123456;Pooling=true;MinimumPoolSize=0;MaximumPoolSize=100;Connection Lifetime=0;"
  },
```

when run this project, i get a problem messages below:

```
08:53:21 ERR] An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs.EntityFrameworkCore.BackgroundJobsDbContext'.
System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: minimumpoolsize (Parameter 'keyword')
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.GetProperty(String keyword)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String keyword, Object value)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.GetPoolAndSettings()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlRelationalConnection.CreateDbConnection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.get_DbConnection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.CreateDbCommand(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, Guid commandId, DbCommandMethod commandMethod)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
```

then i attempt to deleted about pool settings in connection string. and i still got a problem below:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=psi_pg_dev;User ID=chaoyi;Password=123456"
  },
```

```
09:17:58 ERR] Failed executing DbCommand (18ms) [Parameters=[@__now_0='?' (DbType = DateTime), @__p_1='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT a."Id", a."ConcurrencyStamp", a."CreationTime", a."ExtraProperties", a."IsAbandoned", a."JobArgs", a."JobName", a."LastTryTime", a."NextTryTime", a."Priority", a."TryCount"
FROM "AbpBackgroundJobs" AS a
WHERE NOT (a."IsAbandoned") AND (a."NextTryTime" <= @__now_0)
ORDER BY a."Priority" DESC, a."TryCount", a."NextTryTime"
LIMIT @__p_1
[09:17:58 ERR] An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs.EntityFrameworkCore.BackgroundJobsDbContext'.
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P01: relation "AbpBackgroundJobs" does not exist
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|194_0(NpgsqlConnector connector, Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
  Exception data:
    Severity: ERROR
    SqlState: 42P01
    MessageText: relation "AbpBackgroundJobs" does not exist
    Position: 186
    File: parse_relation.c
    Line: 1376
    Routine: parserOpenTable
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P01: relation "AbpBackgroundJobs" does not exist
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|194_0(NpgsqlConnector connector, Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  Exception data:
    Severity: ERROR
    SqlState: 42P01
    MessageText: relation "AbpBackgroundJobs" does not exist
    Position: 186
    File: parse_relation.c
    Line: 1376
    Routine: parserOpenTable
[09:17:58 ERR] 42P01: relation "AbpBackgroundJobs" does not exist
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P01: relation "AbpBackgroundJobs" does not exist
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|194_0(NpgsqlConnector connector, Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs.EntityFrameworkCore.EfCoreBackgroundJobRepository.GetWaitingListAsync(Int32 maxResultCount)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AsyncInterceptorBase.ProceedAsynchronous[TResult](IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo)
   at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAbpMethodInvocationAdapterWithReturnValue`1.ProceedAsync()
   at Volo.Abp.Uow.UnitOfWorkInterceptor.InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
   at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAsyncAbpInterceptorAdapter`1.InterceptAsync[TResult](IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo, Func`3 proceed)
   at Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs.BackgroundJobStore.GetWaitingJobsAsync(Int32 maxResultCount)
   at Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs.BackgroundJobWorker.DoWorkAsync(PeriodicBackgroundWorkerContext workerContext)
   at Volo.Abp.BackgroundWorkers.AsyncPeriodicBackgroundWorkerBase.DoWorkAsync()
  Exception data:
    Severity: ERROR
    SqlState: 42P01
    MessageText: relation "AbpBackgroundJobs" does not exist
    Position: 186
    File: parse_relation.c
    Line: 1376
    Routine: parserOpenTable
[09:17:58 ERR] ---------- Exception Data ----------
Severity = ERROR
InvariantSeverity = ERROR
SqlState = 42P01
MessageText = relation "AbpBackgroundJobs" does not exist
Position = 186
File = parse_relation.c
Line = 1376
Routine = parserOpenTable
```

Plz, how can i fixed that. :) thanks all.

Comment: Will be fixed in abp 4.3. https://github.com/abpframework/abp/pull/7562

Answer (score 0):

If you use services.AddDbContextPool<...  so poolSize has default preset - max 128. Thus, just remove from con string  MinimumPoolSize=0;MaximumPoolSize=100;
Relevant for .Net Core 5, EF Core 5, Postgres 13
The rest errors you shuold fix according to errors info.